# Using string.Replace to remove special characters is not working

Tags: c#, replace, special-characters

I looked at similar questions on here but still can't figure out why my code is not working.  I am trying to remove the following special characters - ( ) , " ' + . from the individual members of my string array but they are still there when i do a console.writeline of the new string values.  Do i need to escape them?  (i tried and it gave me angry squiggly lines) .
Any help is appreciated

I tried adding escape characters @ and /
I also looked at several similar questions on this site but i figure out why it is not working in my code

```
            StreamReader sw = File.OpenText(file);
            string input = sw.ReadLine();
            string[] values = Regex.Split(input, "\\s+");

            foreach(string word in values)
            {
                int value = 1;
                string word2 = word.ToLower();
                word2.ToLower().Replace(@"(", string.Empty);
                word2.Replace(@")", string.Empty);
                word2.Replace(@":", string.Empty);
                word2.Replace(@";", string.Empty);
                word2.Replace(@".", string.Empty);
                word2.Replace(@",", string.Empty);
                word2.Replace(@"'", string.Empty);
                word2.Replace(@"=", string.Empty);
                word2.Replace(@"-", string.Empty);
```

Comment: String is inmutable. You can never modify a string, only create a new string with a different value. You need to actually take the functions return values and assign them to word2, every time.

Comment: use regex.replace for your reference. use this regex pattern '[):;.,'=-]'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `word2 = word2.Replace(":", string.Empty);`

It returns the replaced value.  It doesn't edit in-place.  Same with all string functions.

Comment: obviously i am new to this...haha   thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You are using regex in your code. so why not shorten it by using this regex pattern. it basically replace word  in values array.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {       
        string[] values = { "abC" , "efg;;" , "hiz]" };
        foreach(string word in values)
         {
           int value = 1;
           string word2 = Regex.Replace(word, @"[):;.,'=-]", "").ToLower();
           Console.WriteLine(word2);
         }

    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`String.Replace` returns the string with the replaced characters, it does not change the variable itself.

You would need to do this:-

```
//...
word2 = word2.Replace(@")", string.Empty);
word2 = word2.Replace(@":", string.Empty);
word2 = word2.Replace(@";", string.Empty);
//etc
```

See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=netframework-4.8) for documentation on `String.Replace`

Answer (score -1):

As others mentioned, strings are [Immutable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/reference-types) and you have to assign the return value back to your array variable. On the side note, to keep your code more manageable and less messy, you can use [Regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex) to do the job quite easily.

All you have to do is,

> Regex pattern = new Regex("[-(),.;:=\"\']");
>   word2 = pattern.Replace(word2.ToLower(), string.Empty);

Regex Pattern `[-(),.;:=\"\']` will have all the characters that need to be replaced.

In this way, you don't have to [Replace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace) it multiple times and can have more control over the strings-to-be-replaced. Either you can have them in a config or pass in through a parameter.